# “How far is __ important?”

Tags: usage

> “How far is X important?”

Does such a question of the above form mean:

> A) Why is X important/unimportant?

or:

> B) Is X important in reality?

or could it be interpreted both ways?

For example:

> “How far is **a knowledge of the past** important in shaping your society’s future?”

Answer (score 4):

Neither. In the given context, ***[how far](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/far)*** means:

> to what extent, degree, or distance

Your example sentence could be reworded as:

"To what extent is knowledge of the past important in shaping your society’s future?”

Comment: Or just "how important", plain and simple.

Answer (score 0):

I think @ЯegDwight nailed it in a comment. “How far” sounds awkward in this context.

To fix this, how can simply use “How important”:

> How important is a knowledge of the past in shaping your society’s future?

Or, alternatively, you could use “How much”, and leave out the word *important* altogether:

> How much does a knowledge of the past shape your society’s future?

Comment: I would disagree your 2 sentences say the same thing. The first asks "how important is it you understand the past to sensibly shape your future?" The second asks "how much effect does a knowledge of the past have on your decisions for the future"

Comment: @WendyG - They may not be 100% identical in meaning, but the differences are subtle and the gist is the pretty much the same.